# jQuery UI first drop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Why does this jQuery not drop the first time it is dropped?

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass('valid');
  }
});
$("#droppable").droppable({
  accept: '.valid',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#droppable').text('dropped');
  }
});
```

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awhitelaw/F4ckV/1/), which shows that the *first* time you drop a *each* green square inside the red one it will revert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

droppable only accepts valid class divs, and at the start of your drag your grenn div does not have this class.  The drag function adds it, but too late for the first drop, but its still there, so subsequent dragdrops work.

Solution: make sure the green div has .valid before first drag event occurs

Comment: Thank you. By adding `start: function() { $(this).addClass('valid'); }` I have made it work. I am still confused by the fact I can see the valid class in firebug but the `drop` cannot see it!

Comment: When I checked the jfiddle exmaple with firebug, there was no valid class present before dragging

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the drop element doesn't present the 'valid' class until after the droppable fires the drop event. A way to correct this is to change the drag event to the start event in the drag element, so the 'valid' class is added to the element before the drop event is fired.

Comment: Solved by adding `start: function() { $(this).addClass('valid'); }`. I am still confused as to how it works for subsequent drags though? When does the valid class get added to those future drags?